# npm ERR! Cannot find module 'encoding'

Tags: node.js, linux, npm

I encounter this problem when am trying to install ganache-cli in my laptop (Kali Linux). The error that I came across is:

```
sudo npm install -g ganache-cli
npm ERR! code MODULE_NOT_FOUND
npm ERR! Cannot find module 'encoding'
```

The debug log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'install', '-g', 'ganache-cli' ]
2 info using npm@5.8.0
3 info using node@v8.11.2
4 verbose npm-session 8012bd73873770d8
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readGlobalPackageData
7 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for ganache-cli@latest Cannot find module 'encoding'
8 verbose stack Error: Cannot find module 'encoding'
8 verbose stack     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
8 verbose stack     at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
8 verbose stack     at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
8 verbose stack     at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
8 verbose stack     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/share/npm/node_modules/pacote/node_modules/make-fetch-happen/node_modules/node-fetch-npm/src/body.js:13:17)
8 verbose stack     at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
8 verbose stack     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
8 verbose stack     at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
8 verbose stack     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
8 verbose stack     at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
8 verbose stack     at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
8 verbose stack     at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
8 verbose stack     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/share/npm/node_modules/pacote/node_modules/make-fetch-happen/node_modules/node-fetch-npm/src/index.js:15:14)
8 verbose stack     at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
8 verbose stack     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
8 verbose stack     at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
9 verbose cwd /home/shirke
10 verbose Linux 4.15.0-kali2-amd64
11 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "ganache-cli"
12 verbose node v8.11.2
13 verbose npm  v5.8.0
14 error code MODULE_NOT_FOUND
15 error Cannot find module 'encoding'
16 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

This error is bugging me a lot as am not able to do any work.

Comment: Hi Welcome to SO. You need to manually install encoding using following command npm install encoding

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO.

You need to manually install encoding using below command to make it work

```
npm install encoding
```